# There's no Microsoft SQL Server when I searched it, do I have to install it?

Tags: sql-server

I have to configure the SQL Server, but when I look for it, I cannot find it. I even search the folders, C:/Windows/SysWOW64/SQLServerManager as indicated, should I install it?

Comment: Type SSMS in the run dialog box, it will throw an exception if its not installed, which means you have to take it from the microsoft website

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be completely sure, try to check the `Local Windows Services` on your PC `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Services` for SQL Server related services, see below. If you have none - you do not have SQL Server installed.

[image]